# Working with average numbers and finding unknown variables?

Tags: average

There is this question I was approached with and I am absolutely stumped on where to even begin to solve it. It goes like this:

Based off the following 4 equations, find the average of $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$.

$$x_1 + \frac{x_2+x_3+x_4}{3} = 25$$

$$x_2 + \frac{x_1+x_3+x_4}{3} = 37$$

$$x_3 + \frac{x_1+x_2+x_4}{3} = 43$$

$$x_4 + \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3} = 51$$

However I'm unsure of how to move on from here or if I am even going in the right direction.

Comment: For more infor than just the average (see @Twieceler's answer below), you could just solve the system of equations using Gaussian Elimination.

Comment: You could multiply each equation by 3 on both sides to remove the fractions and then row reduce it to get somewhere.

Comment: But Gaussian elimination is a *lot* more work than needed to get the requested answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Sum the left-hand sides and the right-hand sides of the 4 equations. What do you get?

Comment: After doing so, I ended up with $6x_1 + 6x_2 + 6x_3 + 6x_4 = 156$, and from there I divided everything by $6$, and then divided everything by $4$. Was this the right approach? The final answer was $6\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @RossMillikan How would I get $5\frac{1}{3}$ as the coefficient?I found out that $6$ is definitely not right however after recalculating I am getting a coefficient of $4$.

Comment: @Qasim:  I didn't read carefully enough.  You get a full $x_1$ from the first one and three thirds from the last three, so a total of $2$.  Similarly for the others.